# Filtering list values, should I create a new list or delete values from the original one

Tags: java, algorithm, list

Say I have a list that contains either single values, or value ranges. Now if I add a new value or a range to this list, it might overlap with none to multiple of the current values/ranges. All these overlapping objects should be combined to create a new instance, that should be added to the list, meanwhile the objects that got included in the new instance need to be deleted from the original list.

So my question is, should I really delete those objects from the list or create a new list on every iteration. That is, put to code:

**Solution 1**

```
for (Range newObj : newItems){
  Iterator it = oList.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()){
    Range o = it.next();
    if (canCombine(newObj, o)){
      newObj = combine(newObj, o);
      it.remove();
    }
  }
  oList.add(newObj);
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
for (Range newObj : newItems){
  List newList = new ArrayList();
  for (Range o : oList){
    if (canCombine(newObj, o)){
      new = combine(newObj, o);
    } else {
      newList.add(o);
    }
  }
  newList.add(newObj);
  oList = newList;
}
```

Maybe another solution is even better. If so, kindly let me know.

Comment: "Maybe another solution is even better" This is correct: [interval trees provide a better solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: The fact that you're using Object in your list smells bad to me.

Why not define a Range(from,to) object. That would encapsulate single values and a non-zerro range. Your combination logic wouldn't have to introspect on what object its been passed (as I suspect you currently do)

Comment: @BrianAgnew I don't actually use Object, this was for the lack of a good name for the object. I actually use an abstract class, that is implemented by a range and by a single value class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks. It would probably be the best solution, but without native Java support for this data structure, it probably is too complex for the task at hand. So could you still answer, which of the solutions given here is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid creating newList every time you iterate your newItems or you can avoid the creation of new list at all.

```
for (Object newObj : newItems){  
    for(int i=0;i<oList.size();i++){
        if (canCombine(newObj, oList.get(i))){ 
          newObj = combine(newObj,  oList.get(i)); 
          oList.remove(i);
        }    
      }  
      oList.add(newObj); 
    }
```

Comment: This should use iterators. But I see what you mean. I'll improve the question.